# scp multiple files with different names from source and destination

Tags: linux, bash, file, scp

I am trying to scp multiple files from source to destination.The scenario is the source file name is different from the destination file

Here is the SCP Command i am trying to do

```
scp /u07/retail/Bundle_de.properties rgbu_fc@<fc_host>:/u01/projects/MultiSolutionBundle_de.properties
```

Basically i do have more than 7 files which i am trying seperate scps to achieve it. So i want to club it to a single scp to transfer all the files

Few of the scp commands i am trying here -

```
$  scp /u07/retail/Bundle_de.properties rgbu_fc@<fc_host>:/u01/projects/MultiSolutionBundle_de.properties

$ scp /u07/retail/Bundle_as.properties rgbu_fc@<fc_host>:/u01/projects/MultiSolutionBundle_as.properties

$ scp /u07/retail/Bundle_pt.properties rgbu_fc@<fc_host>:/u01/projects/MultiSolutionBundle_pt.properties

$ scp /u07/retail/Bundle_op.properties rgbu_fc@<fc_host>:/u01/projects/MultiSolutionBundle_op.properties
```

I am looking for a solution by which i can achieve the above 4 files in a single scp command.

Comment: move all the file in a single folder and then zip it using `tar` or `gzip` and then make `SCP`

Comment: @smn_onrocks : If i zip it and do the scp . Still i do have the source file names,So i need to manually rename the files as in the destination.The Destination files should not have the source file names.Since those files are important for the other installation purpose .

Comment: you cane automate the rename process using `MV` I can provide u some `.sh` file for this kind of things

Comment: @smn_onrocks : Can u pls provide your rename process in more detail.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU tar, ssh and bash:

```
tar -C /u07/retail/ -c Bundle_{de,as,pt,op}.properties | ssh user@remote_host tar -C /u01/projects/ --transform 's/.*/MultiSolution\&/' --show-transformed-names -xv
```

If you want to use globbing (`*`) with filenames:

```
cd /u07/retail/ && tar -c Bundle_*.properties | ssh user@remote_host tar -C /u01/projects/ --transform 's/.*/MultiSolution\&/' --show-transformed-names -xv
```

---

> `-C`: change to directory
>
> `-c`: create a new archive
>
> `Bundle_{de,as,pt,op}.properties`: bash is expanding this to `Bundle_de.properties Bundle_as.properties Bundle_pt.properties Bundle_op.properties` before executing tar command
>
> `--transform 's/.*/MultiSolution\&/'`: prepend `MultiSolution` to filenames
>
> `--show-transformed-names`: show filenames after transformation
>
> `-xv`: extract files and verbosely list files processed

Comment: I like this answer (and I always forget GNU tar's `--transform` tool).  I think it's better than mine, except if you use `scp -u` to reduce time when only a few files change (this solution has to transfer all the files every time).  But if you're doing that, you probably want `rsync` instead.

Comment: @Cyrus : This is what exactly i am looking for. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a straightforward loop in any standard POSIX shell:

```
for i in de as pt op
do scp "/u07/retail/Bundle_$i.properties" "rgbu_fc@<fc_host>:/u01/projects/MultiSolutionBundle_$i.properties"
done
```

Alternatively, you could give the files new names locally (copy, link, or move), and then transfer them with a wildcard:

```
dir=$(mktemp -d)
for i in de as pt op
do cp "/u07/retail/Bundle_$i.properties" "$dir/MultiSolutionBundle_$i.properties"
done
scp "$dir"/* "rgbu_fc@<fc_host>:/u01/projects/"
rm -rf "$dir"
```

Comment: This worked for me if i had a limited files to copy.! But the scenario is we wont write any shell script or any scripting to achieve this goal. We ultimately need a handy way to copy the files. So i am looking for a one liner to achieve it. Since the number of files will keep on increasing or decreasing.

Comment: Then you just change the `for` loop to `for i in "$path"/Bundle_??.properties; do cp "$i" "$dir/MultiSolution${i##*/}"; done` or the like.  You don't need spoon-feeding, do you?

Comment: I got the ultimate logic of your answer.Thanks for your inputs..!!.